# Using knitr to write a paper for JSS

Tags: r, latex, pdflatex

I am writing a paper for the Journal of Statistical Software documenting my package. Their style files have some facilities for Sweave output but nothing for knitr. I imagine i would have to customise the *knitrout* environment.

I wanted to know if anybody (maybe better than me at knitr and Latex) has done it already or has any suggestions.

Many thanks, Marco

Comment: You may have to use `knitr` to produce latex output.  The knitr [examples page](http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/minimal/) has instructions for doing this.  See in particular this [example](https://github.com/yihui/knitr-examples/blob/master/005-latex.Rtex).

Comment: If you want to use Rmarkdown, see the https://github.com/rstudio/rticles package which provides a JSS template.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I am using knitr. What I wanted to know is how to reconcile jss.cls with knitr formatting, lie shaded code, etc.

Answer (score 5):

`render_sweave()`  renders knitr output in the Sweave default style which I think JSS expects.    Also for JSS you need `options(prompt="R> ")`

Comment: Thanks. I don't know about this as it would mean switching back to sweave. To be honest, I am beginning to dislike all this Sweave/knitr reproducible computing. I am trying to submit a package to CRAN and i just can't get the vignettes right. the paper copiles in R and check_vignettes gives no errors! It would take a fraction of the time to just submit the pdf.

Answer (score 2):

Can't you write your paper using Sweave and the use the `Sweave2knitr` function from the knitr-package to turn it into a knitr-file?

Comment: That entirely defeats the purpose. Namely, to write in the lightweight knitr syntax rather than the rather heavy and unreadable Sweave syntax.

Comment: Well, actually I thought of creating something like a template of your final document using Sweave and the JSS style files (which I assumed where only for the Latex part of the document), then convert this template to knitr and fill in the content.

Comment: Sure I could write a sweave version of it. It would just take more time. I am beginning to find it quite frustrating this coexistence of sweave and knitr. thank you for your comments.